# how to select specific column order in PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I want to select and write specific column names as I want how can I do that ?
the situation is :

```
$stockQuery = mysql_query("SELECT stokId,urunAdi,tlFiyat,stokMiktari,tlFiyat*stokMiktari,urunGrup,maliyetTipi FROM proje_stok where projeID =".$projeID);
```

but I do want to select lik

```
select * from proje_stok where ......
```

and my current writing code is

```
while($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($stockQuery)) {
$col = 0;
if ($col == 0) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $order);
    $col++;
}
foreach($row_data as $key=>$value) {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
   $col++;

}
$row++;
$order++;
}
```

Instead of that I want to use the code like

```
foreach($row_data as $key=>$value) {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value['HEREWHATIWANTTOPUTCOLUMNNAME']);
   $col++;
}
```

is there any suggestion to deal with ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

```
$col = $row = $order = 1;
if ($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($stockQuery))
{
    foreach ($row_data as $key => $value)
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(++$col, $row, $key);

    do
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col = 1, ++$row, $order++);
        foreach ($row_data as $value)
           $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(++$col, $row, $value);
    }
    while ($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($stockQuery));
}
```

Comment: It does almost what I did, I want to write specifically to the cells like  `
if($row == 1){
$value['someColumnName1'];
}
else if($row == 2){
$value['someColumnName2'];
}
`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps `ksort($row_data)` to organize the result?